# List all the subcategories of a parent categoriey

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to list all subcategories for a particular parent category in WordPress, I am new in PHP so I need some help any help would be rally appreciate, I want something like below code

```
<h2>Maine Category 1</h2>

<div class="row">
<div class="col">Subcategory 1</div>
<div class="col">Subcategory 2</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col">Subcategory 3</div>
<div class="col">Subcategory 4</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col">Subcategory 5</div>
<div class="col">Subcategory 6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
NOTE : **15 is your parent category id .**

```
$args = array('child_of' => 15);
$categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach($categories as $category) { 
    echo '<p>Category: <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </p> ';
    echo '<p> Description:'. $category->description . '</p>';
    echo '<p> Post Count: '. $category->count . '</p>';  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wp_list_categories`.

Sample:

`$parentcat = $i;//category id
wp_list_categories("depth=2&child_of=" . $parentcat . "&title_li=");`

or you can Try this in another process.

```
<?php 
$cat_id = get_query_var('cat');

if( ! empty( $cat_id ) ) {
   $category = get_category( $cat_id, ARRAY_A );

  if( ! empty( $category ) ) {
     // parent category
     if( $category['parent'] === '0' ) {

        // get child IDs
        $terms = get_term_children( $cat_id, 'category' );

        foreach( $terms as $term_id ) {
            $child_category = get_term( $term_id, 'category' );

            // if you need the category
            $category_name = $child_category->name;




            // do whatever you like with the categories now...
             echo '<p>Category: <a href="' . get_category_link( $child_category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $child_category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $child_category->name.'</a> </p> ';
    }

} else { 
// in child category
    // do the regular loop here, if ( have_posts() ) ...
  }
 }
}
?>
```

also it's posted [Here](https://gist.github.com/mpeshev/cb1cd3c56d06017b3d87)

hope it can help you :)

Comment: Hi Lemon, Thanks for your prompt reply, let me try with this code.